# Extract characters from special input

Tags: c++

In an exercise the input is given in the following format:

```
{a, b, a, d, e} // some random example
```

The input starts with the character **{** and ends with **}**.

I want to refer to each small English letter in the standard way "**x = above_input, x[0] = a, x[1] = b,...,x[4] = e**".

Is there an efficient way to this?

For example i tried to extract the small English letters and store them in a vector or i tried to convert the input somehow into a set, but i did not work out.

Comment: Also, on a side note, how do you want to handle duplicates?

Comment: [std::regex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex)

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 No overkill for the requirements the OP states (backtracking and whatnot).

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 I don't think that the question is focussed enough, or already has a research effort background, that it is reasonably answerable here. The link and the idea are a good starter for the OP though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a good old for loop to recognise the characters you want and put them in a string instead of vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string ip;
    std::getline(std::cin, ip);
    std::string str;
    for (const char& character : ip) {
        if (character >= 'a' && character <= 'z') {
            str.push_back(character);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```